# Building a dictionary from file, while getting rid of some characters in values

Tags: python, dictionary

I a **.txt file** that contains sample lines:

```
YAL012W "1185,"
YAL069W "315,"
YAL068W-A   "255,"
YAL068C "363,"
YAL067W-A   "228,"
YAL067C "1782,"
YAL066W "309,"
YAL065C "387,"
YAL064W-B   "381,"
YAL064C-A   "381,"
YAL064W "285,"
YAL063C-A   "291,"
YAL063C "3969,"
YAL062W "1374,"
YAL061W "1254,"
YAL060W "1149,"
YAL059C-A   "423,"
YAL059W "639,"
YAL058W "1509,"
```

column1=gene_name

column2=size

My ultimate goal is to save it as a dictionary. This is what I have so far:

```
dic={}
with open('inputfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f: 
        fields=line.split()
        gene_name=fields[0]
        size=fields[1]
        a=int(size[1:-2])
        dic[gene_name]=a
print dic
```

This is the output:

```
  {'YAL012W': 1185}
```

It only prints the first line - my built dictionary contains only one line.

Please note, I looked through other building dictionaries from a file and could not find an answer to this question. Therefore, this should be duplicate question. If so, please let me know

Comment: This works fine. Are you sure the file is the same format as the sample above?

Comment: Hi, just to be clear, are you saying that the resulting dict only contains one (k,v) pair? Have you check its length?

Comment: Is it possible it's only reading one line? Put a print statement inside the loop and see what comes up.

Comment: Code works for me. You might get that result, however, if python only sees one line, e.g. doesn't recognize newline characters properly. Has the file been generated on the system that you are working on?

Comment: @ColinBasnett Yep, I tried that.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Yes, it was. I think it must be the file that Python only sees one line. I will try to re-generate the file. thanks

Comment: Yes, it is. I must be doing something wrong. or running the wrong file. Trying to recheck everything @MichalFrystacky

Comment: @MichalFrystacky Hi everyone, I opened another file and first opened it in excel and then saved tab-delimited. It must have been something with my file. Thank you so much for your help!!